# Is there a fast way to initialize multiple buttons numbered 1-10 using for loop? (Android Application)

Tags: android, android-view

I have an init method that finds each button using findViewById(R.id.pin1) and then sets an onclick method that has the method write to a bluetooth output stream.

```
    Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pin1);
    myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String msg = "1".toString();
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(msg.getBytes());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                error();
            }
        }
    });
```

Very quite literally, all I change is the 1 to 2 and so on. So the next code segment is:

```
    Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pin2);
    myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String msg = "2".toString();
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(msg.getBytes());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                error();
            }
        }
    });
```

I tried a few things like making a string like string pinButton = "pin" + i.toString() and then R.id.pinButton but it doesn't work. (That is, the i is in a forloop that I surrounded the code with)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can `switch` on the `button id` and call the same `onClick()` for each `button` in xml
Then you just change the `msg` variable depending on the `id` that was clicked

```
@Override
    public void myClick(View v) {
      String msg = "";
       switch (v.getId())
       {
             case (R.id.button1):
              msg = "1";
              break;
              case (R.id.button2):
              msg = "2";
             break
      }
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(msg.getBytes());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            error();
        }
    }
});
```

To set the `onClick()` in xml just do this for each `Button`

```
<Button
    ...
    android:onClick="myClick"/> // name this whatever you want the method to be called and do the same for each Button
```

Also, you don't need to call `toString()` on `msg` since it is already a `String`

Comment: Bad downvote. +1 to restore the natural balance of the Androidverse.

Answer (score 1):

Make your own `OnClickListener`, and then attach it by doing `button.setOnClickListener(new MyButtonListener(number));`

```
private class MyButtonListener extends OnClickListener {

    private int mNumber;

    public MyButtonListener(int number) {
        mNumber = number;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String msg = String.valueOf(mNumber);
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(msg.getBytes());
        } catch (IOException e) {
           error();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do this by tagging the button. 
Tagging a view lets you assign data to it for later retrieval.

```
Button pin1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pin1);
Button pin2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pin2);
pin1.setTag("1");
pin2.setTag("2");

OnClickListener myOnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String msg = v.getTag();
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(msg.getBytes());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            error();
        }
    }
}
pin1.setOnClickListener(myOnClickListener);
pin2.setOnClickListener(myOnClickListener);
```